# When you are trying to edit question tags, new tag appears

Tags: bug, tags, russian-stackoverflow, inline-tag-editor

For example, in this question: [Phalcon: setVars() и Volt](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/371085/15479).

> [image]

Probably, it's related to migration. The question had this tag before migration from hashcode, but later this tag was removed.

Comment: Related: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4681/15479.